# Getting different instances of @RequestScoped CDI bean during same request

Tags: jakarta-ee, ejb, cdi

On WildFly 8/10, I have a simple SLSB firing a CDI event:

```
@Stateless
@Remote(CDITestRemote.class)
@Local(CDITestLocal.class)
public class CDITestBean implements CDITestRemote, CDITestLocal {

    @Inject
    private Event<IVolumeEvent> events;

    @Override
    public String insert(final String value) {
        final IVolumeEvent event = new VolumeEvent();
        events.fire(event);

        return String.format("value: %s", value);
    }
}
```

and an `@ApplicationScoped` "CDI event observer" for the type of events fired by the EJB:

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class VolumeEventObserver {

    private Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(VolumeEventObserver.class);

    @Inject
    private TransactionHandler txHandler;

    public void inProgress(
            @Observes(during = TransactionPhase.IN_PROGRESS) final IVolumeEvent event) {
        logger.info("@Observes progress() {}", String.valueOf(txHandler));
    }

    public void afterSuccess(
            @Observes(during = TransactionPhase.AFTER_SUCCESS) final IVolumeEvent event) {
        logger.info("@Observes success() {}", String.valueOf(txHandler));
    }

    public void afterFailure(
            @Observes(during = TransactionPhase.AFTER_FAILURE) final IVolumeEvent event) {
        logger.info("@Observes failure() {}", String.valueOf(txHandler));
    }

}
```

`TransactionHandler` is a `@RequestScoped` CDI bean:

```
@RequestScoped
public class TransactionHandler {
    // some methods here...    
}
```

When I make a call to `insert()` on an instance of the EJB injected into a REST resource, I am seeing the same instance of `TransactionHandler` in any observer method in `VolumeEventObserver` during a request to the REST endpoint as expected:

```
11:23:58,476 INFO  [VolumeEventObserver] (default task-11) @Observes progress() TransactionHandler@7687eead
11:23:58,479 INFO  [VolumeEventObserver] (default task-11) @Observes success() TransactionHandler@7687eead
```

But when I make a remote EJB call, I see **different** instances during the same request:

```
11:42:01,461 INFO  [VolumeEventObserver] (EJB default - 2) @Observes progress() TransactionHandler@2e65f10d
11:42:01,463 INFO  [VolumeEventObserver] (EJB default - 2) @Observes success() TransactionHandler@2a5a7019
```

So `TransactionHandler` does not seem to be request scoped.

JSR-299 says that request scope is active:

> during any remote method invocation of any EJB, during any
>   asynchronous method invocation of any EJB [...]

And since there is no `ContextNotActiveException`, I suppose request scope is active - so why am I getting different instances anyway?

It is the same thread (as can be seen from the log entries) and also the transaction is the same.

Comment: I don't think an EJB remote call can be considered as a request (well, at least in the spec), so using @RequestScoped beans during such a call could give hazardous results.

Comment: I don't see what you mean - if the spec and also the WELD reference says "The request and application scopes are also active: during invocations of EJB remote methods" then I simply expect @RequestScoped beans to work.

Comment: Do you have any other mean to find out if the TransactionHandler is the same? You could be calling `String.value()` on different objects proxy-ing the same instance of TransactionHandler (as it is @RequestScoped, you get a proxy and not the real instance injected).

Comment: Well, I have tested your case with OpenEJB and I get the same instance of TransactionHandler. Maybe this is a problem with wildfly...

Comment: Thanks, it is good to know that it works as expected with OpenEJB! To your previous comment - I added a UUID field and the value is different.

Answer (score 0):

The behavior you are seeing is compliant to the spec.  The spec says that request context is active during the remote EJB call.  It does not say that repeated calls to the same bean operate within a single request.

Comment: This is not about repeated calls, it is a single call, same thread, same transaction.

Comment: Ah ha, after rereading your question, I realized that your issue is that you get a different instance AFTER the transaction completes.

Answer (score 0):

Just a shot in the dark: did you try using this one?

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class VolumeEventObserver {

    private Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(VolumeEventObserver.class);

    @Inject
    private Instance<TransactionHandler> txHandler;

    public void inProgress(
        @Observes(during = TransactionPhase.IN_PROGRESS) final IVolumeEvent event) {
        logger.info("@Observes progress() {}", String.valueOf(txHandler.get()));
    }

}
```

Maybe "Instance" will do the trick.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I'll see to try that when I get to it. By now I actually think it is quite acceptable that you can't count on state originating a transaction still being there when the transaction has completed.